# Rust equivalent to Swift's extension methods to a protocol?

Tags: rust, extension-methods, traits

In Swift I can attach extension methods to any of `struct`, `enum` or `protocol`(same with `trait` in Rust).

```swift
protocol Foo1 {
    func method1() -> Int 
}
extension Foo1 {
    func method2() {
        print("\(method1())")
    }
}
```

Then all types conforming the protocol `Foo1` now all have `method2()`. 
This is very useful to build "method chaining" easily.

How to do same in Rust? This doesn't work with an error.

```rust
struct Kaz {}

impl Foo for Kaz {}

trait Foo {
    fn sample1(&self) -> isize { 111 } 
}

impl Foo {
    fn sample2(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.sample1());
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Kaz {};
    x.sample1();
    x.sample2();
}
```

Here's the error.

```
warning: trait objects without an explicit `dyn` are deprecated
  --> src/main.rs:13:6
   |
13 | impl Foo {
   |      ^^^ help: use `dyn`: `dyn Foo`
   |
   = note: `#[warn(bare_trait_objects)]` on by default

error[E0599]: no method named `sample2` found for type `Kaz` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:22:7
   |
3  | struct Kaz {}
   | ---------- method `sample2` not found for this
...
22 |     x.sample2();
   |       ^^^^^^^ method not found in `Kaz`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Rust, you can use [`extension traits`](http://xion.io/post/code/rust-extension-traits.html), that is a trait with a generic implementation for all types `T` that implement the base trait:

```
struct Kaz {}

impl Foo for Kaz {}

trait Foo {
    fn sample1(&self) -> isize { 111 } 
}

trait FooExt {
    fn sample2(&self);
}

impl<T: Foo> FooExt for T {
    fn sample2(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.sample1());
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Kaz {};
    x.sample1();
    x.sample2();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e784b921a49eaadf50396b646225f89e)

Comment: there is also https://crates.io/crates/extend

Comment: According to this https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html.

Can't we just do

`trait Foo {
    fn sample1(&self) -> isize;
    fn sample2(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.sample1())
    }
}`

Comment: @SaintTail what if you don't control the definition of `Foo` (e.g. it comes from a library written by someone else)?

Comment: @Jmb Yeah, thank for provinding an example. I'm still learning rust and coming from swift seem like rust does not allow `impl trait` without `for` is that right?

Comment: Thanks for the crate @MücahitŞenol, but it doesn't work if there are multiple extensions for same type in single module.

Comment: @eonil if you have multiple extensions, you must [give them different names with e.g. `#[ext(name = FooExt2)]`](https://docs.rs/extend/1.1.2/extend/#configuration)

Comment: @Jmb  Oh that's great. I'll try!