# How to use methods of inner struct in Rust without accessing fields of outer structure?

Tags: rust

I want Complex numbers to be implemented for my custom type and found num_complex crate with it's Complex struct, for my complex nums I want to have almost the same name as their parent type (like custom_nums and custom_nums_c).

And I decided to do something like

```
pub struct custom_nums_c(pub Complex<custom_nums>);
```

and implement Deref trait.

And this works fine if I want to access such fields like real part or imaginary part but I can't get access to methods implemented for `Complex<T>` struct
(for instance - I can't use + operator for two objects of type custom_nums_c but suddenly I can use `custom_nums_c.sin()`)

How can fix this?

Comment: What `Add` impl do you have?

Comment: I expected trait implementations to be inherited from Complex<T> struct, thus there is no implementation of Add in my code (but there is implementation  [here](https://docs.rs/num-complex/latest/src/num_complex/lib.rs.html#724-731) ) my struct is only a wrapper

Comment: *"and implement Deref trait"* – there is your problem, your type isn't a smart pointer so it shouldn't implement `Deref`, it should implement the traits you want to use instead.

Comment: Well, I got It that traits still have to be implemented but imho `Deref` is ok if I want to use not `num.0.re` but `num.re` when accessing fields of inner struct

Comment: Well it's ok if you like hacks, it's definitely [not recommended](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/predictability.html?highlight=deref#only-smart-pointers-implement-deref-and-derefmut-c-deref)

Comment: As @cafce25 pointed out, using `Deref` to mimic inheritance from OO languages is an antipattern, as explained in more details [here](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/anti_patterns/deref.html).

Comment: The question here is why do you need a wrapper type at all if you want it to support everything that the wrapped type supports? I suspect what you really want is an alias (`type CustomNumsC = Complex<CustomNums>`), with an [extension trait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58852750/5397009) if you need to add custom functions to the type.